ckan 2.10 update cookies to secure
I am using ckan version 2.10.3 and had updated the REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE=true and beaker.session.secure=true.
After updated the cookies secure to TRUE, I have encountered error
400 Bad Request
The CSRF token is missing

I tried to update the ckan.auth.enable_cookie_auth_in_api=false as well, but the error,CSRF token is missing is still appearing ..
The CSRF token is missing error prompts when I tried to login to CKAN.
Can someone please enlighten me? What else do I have to set, if i need the cookies to be secure?
Everything is working fine when the cookies is not secure.

What URL are you using to access your project?

@CBroe I'm using https

I'm using http://localhost:5000 and also have another environment that is hosting on https://hellxxxo.com

On localhost, it should work without HTTPS as well. Can you show what the Set-Cookie header looks like? (Minus potentially sensitive info.)
